# Prove there is no solution to $x^{3}\equiv 2\pmod {151}$

Tags: modular-arithmetic

I tried to prove by contradiction.
Suppose there is a solution so:$$\frac {x^{3}-2 }{151}\in \Bbb Z$$
$$x^{3}-2=(x-\sqrt[3]{2})(x^{2}+\sqrt[3]{2}x+(\sqrt[3]{2})^{2})$$
and $\sqrt[3]{2}$ is irrational number.

151 is a prime number,the Euclid's lemma implies that 151 must to divide at least one of the products.

I know that the product of a rational and irrational number is irrational and $(x-\sqrt[3]{2})$ is irrational because of a rational number minus irrational number is irrational.

So prime number cannot divide an irrational number.

I don't want  to prove this using irrational numbers theorems.

Comment: This should help you spot the flaws in your attempted proof: replace $151$ by $41$: nothing changes in the proof because you didn't use any particular property of $151$ aside from primality. But note that $41\mid5^3-2$. Some questions to reflect: what does it mean that "$151$ divides $x-\sqrt[3]2$". Does $151$ "divide" $151\sqrt[3]2$? What does Euclid's lemma _really_ say?

Comment: If a prime divides the product of two numbers, it must divide at least one of those numbers. 
I understand my mistake.
divides mean $\frac{(x-\sqrt[3]{2})}{151} \in \Bbb Z$

Comment: The product of two _integers_, not just arbitrary complex numbers: $5$ is prime and $5\mid5\pi\times\frac1\pi$, but neither $5\pi/5$ nor $\frac1\pi/5$ is integer. FYI: the general notion of divisibility is defined otherwise, note just by requiring that the quotient be integer. You may be interested in https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unique_factorization_domain

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Hint:**
Suppose by way of contradiction that there exists an integer $x$, with $x^3 \equiv 2 \pmod{151}$.

Taking the 50th power of this relation gives
$$x^{150} \equiv 2^{50} \equiv 32 \pmod{151}. $$ 
At the same time, [Fermat's little theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fermat%27s_little_theorem) tells us that
$$x^{151} \equiv x \pmod{151}. $$
What can you conclude from this?

Comment: you mean $$x^{151}\equiv x\pmod{151}$$
and $$x^{151}\equiv 64\pmod{151}$$
so: $$x=64 \\and\\ 64^{3} \not \equiv 2\pmod{151}$$
It's enough?

Comment: @Asaf I don't see how you got $x^{151} \equiv 64 \pmod{151}$.

Comment: $x^{151}\pmod{151}\equiv[\underbrace{x\pmod{151}\cdot x\pmod{151}\cdots x\pmod{151}}_{151\text{ times}}]\pmod{151} $ 

so I multiply by 2

Comment: @Asaf If $x^{150} \equiv 32 \pmod{151}$, multiplying by $x$ I get that $x^{151} \equiv 32x \pmod{151}$, rather than $64$. You can't say that $x \equiv 2 \pmod{151}$ because it's *definitely* not true.

Comment: ok,thanks.
I don't understand how to prove there is no solution.

Comment: @Asaf consider both expressions we have for $x^{151} \pmod{151}$.

Comment: ,you mean this:
$$x^{151}\equiv x\pmod{151}$$
$$x^{151}\equiv 32x\pmod{151}$$
so,$x\equiv 32x\pmod{151}$ and there is no solution for that?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/45848/discussion-between-asaf-and-user1337).